# error communicate between backgroundjs and contentScriptjs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I got this error with below code :

```
Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

my background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log(response.farewell);
    console.log('ytr');
  });
});
```

and my contentScript.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  alert(request.greeting);
});
```

part of my manifest.json

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","contentScript.js"],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }
  ]
```

I wonder what's wrong in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running this code while the devtools window is active.  I can reproduce the problem by running that code from the background page console, but not when a regular tab is active.  Try running console.log("URL = " + tabs[0].url) to see if the active tab is the one you really expect it to be.

Comment: I don't get what u mean, run at where?

Comment: I mean the problem will happen if a developer console is open.  For example, the developer console for a web page is what is opened if you go to Chrome Settings, select "More Tools", and then select "Developer console".  Or you can view your extension's developer console by going to chrome://extensions, check the "developer mode" box, and click on the background.js link to open the developer console for your extension.  If these are the active windows, then sendMessage will show the error you are seeing.  Try using the console.log command I suggested to see the URL the message is being sent to